# Talend expression for calculate an age

Tags: talend

I use the talend open studion for Big Data 6.3.0, i create an job and a composant tMap. I want determine the age of customer witch i have her customer.BIRTH_DAY,
i tried this

```
Mathematical.INT(TalendDate.formatDate("yyyy",TalendDate.getCurrentDate()))- Mathematical.INT(TalendDate.formatDate("yyyy", customer.BIRTH_DATE))
```

expression but i find this error :

> Error in the component's properties:AGE cannot be resolved to a
>   variable

I m sure that you can help me here.
thank you for all

Comment: You did not declared your variable `AGE`, you need to add a column named `AGE` in the tmap and in the output schema.

Answer (score 1):

You can add in your tmap the expression :

```
Math.round(TalendDate.diffDate(TalendDate.getCurrentDate(),row18.date,"dd") / 365 )
```

And replace `row18.date` by your date column (you need a date format column)

Comment: Thank you! That worked for me! You saved me :) Your answer should be the accepted one.